# How to convert text into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, file, text, dictionary, text-files

I have a text file that I want to open and turn into a dictionary, like this:

text in text file:

> "During the last ten years, the decrease in interest in reptilian mammals has been barely noticeable."

converted to dictionary:

```
{'during' : 'the', 'the' : 'last', 'last' : 'ten', 'ten' : 'years', 'years' : 'the' ...etc }
```

so that each word in the text file is turned into a key with the following word being its value.

The code I have so far is this:

```
def makedict():
    with open('textfile.txt') as f:
        d = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in f)
        return d
print(makedict())
```

But when I run it, it prints out the first word as the key and the rest as the value, like this:

{ during : 'the last ten years, the decrease in interest in reptilian mammals has been barely noticeable.' }

Comment: Your `makedict` function doesn't return the `d` result that it creates, which is effectively the same as returning `None`.

Comment: I tried that now, it still doesn't do quite what I want it to

Comment: How is this going to work with duplicate keys? You'll end up having the same keys for multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def makedict():
    with open('textfile.txt') as f:
        words = [i.strip().lower() for i in f.read().split()]
        return dict(zip(words[:-1], words[1:]))

>>> makedict()
{'mammals': 'has', 'last': 'ten', 'been': 'barely', 'ten': 'years,', 'during': 'the', 'decrease': 'in', 'interest': 'in', 'reptilian': 'mammals', 'barely': 'noticeable.', 'has': 'been', 'the': 'decrease', 'years,': 'the', 'in': 'reptilian'}
```

Note: Dictionaries must only have unique keys. That means if you have duplicate words, only the most recent value will be in the resulting dictionary, as all previous values are overwritten.

For example notice the dictionary only has

```
{'the': 'decrease'}
```

Instead of

```
{'the': 'last', 'the': 'decrease'}
```

Because you cannot have duplicate keys

I'm not sure how you intend to use this dictionary, but keep that in mind.

Comment: I think he wants the key to be the previous value so he wants each word to be a key

Comment: That is exactly what this does. However with the caveat that I noted about duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
dic={}

p="During the last ten years, the decrease in interest in reptilian mammals has been barely noticeable"


x=zip(p.split(),p.split()[1:])
for k,y in x:
    dic[k]=y
print dic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate keys you should append the values to a list, you also need to use something to strip the commas etc..:

```
from collections import defaultdict
spl = p.split()
d = defaultdict(list)
for a,b in zip(spl, spl[1:]):
    d[a.translate(None,".,")].append(b.translate(None,".,"))
print(d)

defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'last': ['ten'], 'ten': ['years'], 'reptilian': ['mammals'], 'barely': ['noticeable'], 'mammals': ['has'], 'years': ['the'], 'decrease': ['in'], 'been': ['barely'], 'interest': ['in'], 'in': ['interest', 'reptilian'], 'During': ['the'], 'the': ['last', 'decrease'], 'has': ['been']})
```